# I have added a js files in pub/media/custom.js is not updating on frontend in magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript

I have added JS file in pub/media folder and put permission of 777. and given link in content->design->configuration-website

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://#/pub/media/custom.js"></script>
```

After doing this i am getting file and also first time code in browser. but when i am updating this file it's not updating on browser.

Comment: you are create the custom theme ??

Comment: May I know why you put js file in pub folder?

Comment: I think your JS file should be in your theme or module.

Comment: yes,  I have created a custom theme. I put js file in theme or module than on every change I will have to run deploy command I don't want to run every time deploy command.